# Rails association collection build if not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models `Exam`, `User` and `ExamResult`. `ExamResult` contains the records for all the students (User) for exams (Exam). For one particular `Exam` record, there should be one record in `ExamResult` for each student. In the `edit` method of `ExamController`, depending if the `ExamResult` record has been created for one student, I need to build one new record or just skip it. Not sure if this is idiomatic Rails way of doing it.

```
# ExamController

def edit
  User.students.each do |s|
    @exam.exam_results.build(user_id: s.id) unless @exam.exam_results.find_by(user_id: s.id)
  end   
end
```

or this way:

```
def edit
  newIds = User.students.map(&:id) - @exam.exam_results.map(&:user_id)
  newIds.each do |id|
    @exam.exam_results.build(user_id: id)
  end
end
```

Maybe neither is idiomatic Rails. Any suggestions are welcome.

### Edit

Bring `find_or_initialize_by` (recommended by @user3334690) on the table. If I understand the doc correctly, this should do the same as previous two implementations.

```
def edit
  User.students.each do |s|
    @exam.exam_results.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: s.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: You might want to look at a method find_or_create_by (or maybe more appropriate for you is find_or_initialize_by).

Comment: I did this exact thing yesterday, and my code is nearly identical to your second way of doing it.  I am confused about "User.students", but perhaps not all users are students and "students" is a scope?  Regardless, your second example is clear, easily maintainable, easily testable, lower overhead (just two queries), and should work with Rails for the foreseeable future.  One answer below uses dynamic "find" which no longer exists in Rails 4.  The other uses "find_or_create" but in an edit you don't want to "create", just "build".  You're on the right track, carry on.

Comment: Your update using "find_or_intialize_by" should work, but note that it will query the database once for each student.  Your second example will only do two queries.  It might not matter, but if scalability is an issue you're better off with your second example.

Comment: @MichaelChaney Yes, you are right. I overlooked this. Maybe you could write one answer, then I could mark it as solved?

Comment: @AlbertNetymk It's answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your second example:

```
def edit
  newIds = User.students.map(&:id) - @exam.exam_results.map(&:user_id)
  newIds.each do |id|
    @exam.exam_results.build(user_id: id)
  end
end
```

As I said in comments above this will query the database twice regardless of the number of students which will scale much better.  If you're in a really extreme environment you can write it to use only one query along with "pluck" to pull only the "id" column (and avoid the object creation overhead) like this:

```
newIds = User.students.where("users.id not in (select user_id from exam_results where exam_id=?)", @exam.id).pluck(:id)
```

However, the readability is reduced for that.  Your original would also benefit from using "pluck" instead of "map".

One other style note - I would use "new_ids" which is the standard idiomatic way of doing it with Rails.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of build you can use find_or_create_by_user_id in above case.

```
def edit
  User.students.each do |s|
    ExamResult.find_or_create_by_exam_id_and_user_id(exam_id, user_id)
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 3):

there is this way:

```
def edit
    User.students.each do |s|
       ExamResult.where(exam_id: @exam.id, user_id: s.id).first_or_create
    end   
end
```